# Why my code is repeated in async upload file web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In upload async file :
for example if i uploading 3 file `Debug.WriteLine(info.FullName); and _db.Files.Add(New FileDto{FileName=info.Name});` repeated 50 time.means 50 record insert in database.
Why and how to avoid it?
what is my problem?

```
public Task<IEnumerable<FileDesc>> Post()
{

    string folderName = "uploads";
    string PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName);
    string rootUrl = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, String.Empty);
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(PATH);

        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileDesc>>(t =>
        {

            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }

            var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
            {
                var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);

                Debug.WriteLine(info.FullName);//************Repeated******
                _db.Files.Add(New FileDto{FileName=info.Name});//************Repeated******
                return new FileDesc(info.Name, rootUrl + "/" + folderName + "/" + info.Name, info.Length / 1024);
            });
            return fileInfo;
        });

        return task;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
    }
    }
```

[Update]

CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider  :

```
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
    {
        public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path)
            : base(path)
        {
        }

        public override string GetLocalFileName(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {
            var name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName) ? headers.ContentDisposition.FileName : "NoName";
            return name.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

[Update]

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/media/upload",
            limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
            sequentialUploads: true,
            progressInterval: 100,
            maxChunkSize: 10000,
            add: function (e, data) {
                $('#filelistholder').removeClass('hide');
                data.context = $('<div />').text(data.files[0].name).appendTo('#filelistholder');
                $('<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div style="width: 0%;" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning"></div></div>').appendTo(data.context);
                $('#btnUploadAll').click(function () {
                    data.submit();
                });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                data.context.text(data.files[0].name + '... Completed');
                $('<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div style="width: 100%;" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div></div>').appendTo(data.context);
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#overallbar').css('width', progress + '%');
            },
            progress: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                data.context.find('.progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Debug.WriteLine` is in the projection function of `streamProvider.FileData.Select`, so it is executed as many times as there are items in `streamProvider.FileData`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Levesque my question updated ,for example if i uploading 3 file  _db.Files.Add(New FileDto{FileName=info.Name}); repeated 50 time.means 50 record insert in database. how to avoid it? What should I do?

Comment: in the projection function of `streamProvider.FileData.Select` must be repeate 3 time ,bacause i uploaded 3 file but repeated that 50 or more .

Comment: @nocamer, there must be something else going on... What are the names of the 50 files? Are they all distinct? Are they the same as the 3 items you uploaded, but repeated multiple times? I can't see the cause of the issue in the code your posted, perhaps it's somewhere else...

Comment: Excuseme you are right, yes they are the same as the 3 items i uploaded, but repeated multiple times and the files are dameged.

Comment: @nocamer, Where does the `CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` class come from? Could you check the value of `streamProvider.FileData.Count` ?

Comment: 3 Files upload ,streamProvider.FileData.Count=1 in per file and repeated multiple times per file!!

Comment: @nocamer, are you sure there is a single request coming in? Couldn't the problem be on the client side?

Comment: no i'm not sure that's correct ,in debug seems i have multiple request for part of a file! I use jquery uploader .

Comment: Yes jquery uploader call my uploader function in mulultiple time.Thanks a lot @Thomas Levesque for your time.